# How do I tell Visual Studio to look inside the Windows SDK Folder when searching for basic C Headers?

Tags: visual-studio, winapi, sdk, header

If I open a single File with Visual Studio 2022 Community Edition, I run into the following problem:
Every header located in the Windows SDK Folders e.g. stdio.h can't be found.
Is there any way to tell VS where to look for these?

Couriously, if I open a Project Folder, everything works flawlessly.
This Problem also only occurs for certain Users, even though they all have the same rights.

Thank You in advance

Phil

- I already tried reinstalling VS and The Windows SDK, nothing changed
- I already checked the INCLUDE-Paths for the different Users, they are all the same

Comment: Probably related to env variables. To investigate, you can select the "Tools", "Options" menu, in the dialog choose "Projects and Solutions", "Build and Run" and select" Detailed" or "Diagnostic" for the "MSBuild project build output verbosity". Then rebuild your project and compare the differences in the "Build" window output.

Comment: Thanks for the response!
What env variables could be different? Where do I look?
Since the Problem only occurs outside of the Scope of Projecs but when single, independent files (in my case .c) are opened, your suggestion of comparing the Build output doesnt apply here.
Any other ideas on how to spot the Problem?
Best regards,
Phil

Comment: Reading through your question again and your comment... When you open a single file, it's sometimes expected it doesn't work, it depends on Visual Studio config. It's how it (may not) work. Only a project environment (whatever that be : .csproj, makefile, etc.) can really tell Visual Studio where to look for a given file. When you're comparing between users, then you can compare build output or project or Visual Studio configurations.

Answer (score 0):

> If I open a single File

Add folder  of  `stdio.h` to system environment path. Different Windows SDK versions own different direcories.
E.g. SDK 10.0.22000.0

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!
I added the folder to my enviroment variables (System Variables -> Path, added C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt).
Unfortunately, the problem stayed the same. What else could I try?
Best regards,

Comment: Did you install sdk 10.0.22000.0? Can you find stdio.h in the directory?  The direcory above does not contain all header files. You need to find other header files in the subdirectory.